# Not distinguishable testing of pointers and pointer refs in C

Tags: c, oop, pointers

I'm not distinguishable pointers and pointer references in 'if' statement of C. I'm reading the book, Object-Oriented Programming in C (ooc).

Here is the code I can't understand that why use 'element' instead of '*element' in 'if' statement.

It has already the value of address to 'element' (not ref) even 'find' function returns NULL?.

```
void * drop (void * _set, const void * _element)
{
    int * element = find (_set, _element);

    if (element)
        * element = MANY;

    return element;
}
```

Comment: It's a shortcut to check for non-NULL. Equivalent to `if (element != NULL)`.

Comment: `if (element) *element = MANY;` is checking that the pointer value is not `NULL` before dereferencing it. The `if (element)` is evaluating `element` as true or false and in C a `0` value is false and anything else is true.

Answer (score 0):

In C the value `0` is equivalent to false and everything nonzero is true.

Null is predefined to be `0`.

So `if (element)` is checking to see if element is Null or not. If element is Null the statement will be false and it will jump straight to the return, otherwise it will be true and run `*element = MANY;` before returning.

The other way of thinking of this is mentioned in the comments. `if (element)` == `if (element != NULL)`.